# Extracting n-grams with scoring threshold using TfidfVectorizer in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'm using `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer()` in my pipeline to process text to use as features in model training. I want to include bigrams, trigrams and quadgrams as features if they are sufficiently relevant in the text. I can do this with the argument `ngram_range=(1,4)`.

If I use `gensim.models.Phrases()` to extract bigrams, I have the option to set how bigrams should be selected, i.e. I can set a threshold for a minimum PMI/NPMI score. This is more useful than just filtering by frequency because it's an additional indication of how important that word co-occurrence is because it incorporates how often the words appear together vs not together.

However, with sklearn, I can't find a way to score the n-grams - the only thing I can see to do is filter the features overall by max_df and min_df (i.e. the frequency with which the word or combined words appear).

Additionally, words seem to be counted multiple times as single words and bigrams if they are in bigrams.

Here's an example with dummy data. You can see, for example, that the 3rd document ('i love new york city') gets a score above zero for the features 'new', 'new york', 'new york city', 'york', 'city' and 'york city'. It feels to me that it should only score for 'new york city'.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=1.0, min_df=2, ngram_range=(1,4))
new_docs = ['this is new to me', 'new york new york', 'i love new york',
 'new york city is the best', 'have you been to new york city',
 'i am new around here', 'new jersey is another place',
 'it used to be called new amsterdam']
X = tfidf.fit_transform(new_docs)
pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names_out())
```

[image: Words and bigrams as numerical features]

I am keen to use sklearn here because it makes the pipeline a lot easier and means I can easily apply this to test and future data, whereas I'm struggling to find a way to apply the gensim bigram model to new data within my pipeline.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to change the scoring of n-grams so they are selected on things other then frequency?
- Is there a way to avoid n-grams being interpreted several times as different features?